# Using multiple UIWebViews in a UIScrollView

Tags: uiwebview, uiscrollview

I am using 5 UIWebViews in a UIScrollView to show the result of my game. Intention is to allow the user to scroll through the results screen. I had a problem where the UIWebViews won't load when scrolled to the next page. This means the first page will load successfully however when you scroll to Page 2, you will see a white blank page. Page is loaded as I can see the alert which was given in all the 5 pages, but it won't show.

I tried a workaround as mentioned here

[inserting various views into UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773386/inserting-various-views-into-uiscrollview)

http://pinchzoom.com/blog/items/view/1386/one-of-the-problems-with-the-uikit-at-the-moment-is-an-issue-embedding-a-uiwebview-within-a-table

This fixed my problem, however when I submitted the app to iTunes, it got rejected with the following comment.

***"3.3.1 Applications may only use Documented APIs in the manner prescribed by Apple and must not use or call any private APIs."
The non-public API that is included in your application is _documentView***

I would like to fix this issue and resubmit. Can someone help please ?

Thanks
Jugs

Answer (score 0):

Just use *one* WebView for all results (which will scroll if it doesn't fit into the screen).

Comment: I am using horizontal scroll using a Pager control not vertical. The solution you suggested won't work with Pager Controls.

Comment: I really don't want to be the smart ass here, but: For the sake of typical iPhone usability and to get your app shipped with appropriate effort, take the single web view.